# How to automatically fill in @version tags in javadoc?

Tags: java, git, maven, javadoc

I'm writing in Java using Maven for project building and Git for source control.

In javadocs, I would like to follow [the recommendaton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#version) of having the last version when a source file was changed in the `@version` tag. If I were to do this manually, that would be a lot of work. How do I do that automatically?

I don't need files in Git repository to contain the version. I publish my artifacts to Maven Central via OSSRH, and all I care is that javadoc on Maven Central has correct `@version` tags. So I guess I have to insert version numbers during `mvn deploy` run. But in order to know in which version a file was last changed, I need some infromation from my source constol system (git). I don't have any idea how can I combine Git and Maven to do so.

Comment: I would suggest to take a deep look into [maven-javadoc-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html) i never used it for that but it looks like having such things...